# Getting file path in an Airflow DAG

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, airflow

I created an Airflow dag to pull the data from snowflake using the key-factor authentication.

```
import os
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
from slack import WebClient, errors as slack_errors
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import io

# Load the private key
def load_private_key(private_key_path: str, passphrase: str) -> bytes:
    with open(private_key_path, "rb") as key_file:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            key_file.read(),
            password=passphrase.encode(),
            backend=default_backend()
        )
    return private_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.DER,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
    )


def main() -> None:
    snowflake_config = {
        "user": 'DATA',
        "account": Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT"),
        "warehouse": 'MY_WH',
        "database": 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA',
        "schema": 'TPCH_SF100'
    }
    
    # RSA KEY PATH SPECIFIED HERE

    private_key_path = "python_scripts/snowflake_keys/rsa_key.p8"
    passphrase = Variable.get("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE")

def execute_my_script():
    main()

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    'retries': 1,
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='call_app_function_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A DAG to call a function from another folder',
    schedule_interval='0 7 * * *',  # This schedules the DAG to run everyday at 7 AM CST
    catchup=False,
)

run_my_function = PythonOperator(
    task_id='run_my_function',
    python_callable=execute_my_script,
    dag=dag,
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag.cli()
```

When I run the above Airflow dag locally using docker, I am getting an error saying **undefined rsa path python_scripts/snowflake_keys/rsa_key.p8**

This is my folder structure:

```
python_scripts/
│
├── airflow/
│   ├── dags/
│   ├── logs/
│   └── plugins/
│
└── snowflake_keys/
    ├── rsa_key.p8
    └── rsa_key.pub
```

In the docker-compose.yml, I mounted the `python_scripts` folder as below:

```
volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/python_scripts/airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/python_scripts/airflow/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/python_scripts/airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/python_scripts:/opt/python_scripts
```

I don't understand why the dag is unable to pick up the rsa key from the specified path